# How do I disable the SuSE screensaver?

Tags: linux, kde, screensaver, suse

Running SuSE 11.1 w/ KDE 4.  Screensaver keeps blanking out my screen on me and I can't find a setting to turn it off.  A secondary issue is that it also eventually locks my screen on me if screen is blanked for awhile.  Would like to make it stop doing that too!  Hard to use it as a monitoring/display session if it keeps blanking out my screen!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open *Configure Desktop/Personal Settings*.

Go to *Advanced > Power Management > Edit Profiles*, and in the setting for the profile you are using (or all profiles) change the option for **When the system is idle for more than XX min** to **Do nothing**.

In a default install it is set to **Lock screen**, and this overrides ANY timeout and password lock settings you have set for a screensaver in *General > Desktop > Screensaver* (particularly if you have unchecked **Start automatically**, or set the timeout to a period longer than the timeout in the Power Management settings).

This answer was copied from user **Clayton** on the opensuse forum post titled [Screen blanking/locking and 11.1](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2009-04/msg01895.html).

Comment: I was just repeatedly overlooking the "Configure Desktop" icon I guess.  Had to disable the screensaver under Desktop/Screen Saver AND do the above power management profile change.  Thanks!  I'm a long time Linux user and my biggest gripe is the screensaver controls are often hidden and sometimes don't even work right.  IMNSHO, a OS used primarily for servers (argue all you want, we all know it's true) shouldn't ship with screensaver ON by default.  Needs to be off for monitoring purposes anyways.  If I want my screen off, I'll reach over and push the power button!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Easiest Method for My device was to open the system menu.
Under System, which is on the right hand side you click "control Center".  Click "Screensaver" under look and feel; Alternatively, you can type "Screensaver" in the search box.
On the bottom of the screen saver preferences window there is check boxes un-check "Activate Screen Saver When Computer is Idle" and "Lock screen when screensaver is active". When you are done click "Close".

Answer (score 1):

on 11.3 i went to screen locker. opensuse kde  can do a seach for locker and it will pop up

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it's in the Settings app.

So, it's Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock -> Automatic Screen Lock and set to Off.